# Explain the working of this pascal's algorithm

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

```
                  1

                1    1

             1     2     1

          1     3     3     1

       1     4     6     4     1

    1     5     10    10     5    1
```

```py
def pascal(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    else:
        line = [1]
        previous_line = pascal(n-1)
        print(previous_line)
        for i in range(len(previous_line)-1):
            line.append(previous_line[i] + previous_line[i+1])
        line += [1]
    return line

print(pascal(4))
```

**`previous_line = pascal(n-1)`** I didn't get this line along with that for loop `pascal(n-1)` returns an integer and how come we can use `len` function over that integer in for loop

Comment: It's recursive. The function returns a list so `pascal(n-1)` doesn't return an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pascal(n-1)` doesn't return a number, it returns a list. For example `pascal(4-1)` returns the list `[1, 2, 1]`. Then, you use `len` to get the length of that list. Given that length, you create a loop over `i` to find the sums of elements `i` and `i+1` of that list. Then, you append that sum to the new list you are creating.

To get the triangle as in the example image, you need some small adaptions:

```
def pascal(n, indent=""):
    line = [1]
    if n > 1:
        previous_line = pascal(n-1, indent+"  ")
        for i in range(len(previous_line)-1):
            line.append(previous_line[i] + previous_line[i+1])
        line += [1]
    print(indent + "".join([f'{i:4}' for i in line]))
    return line

pascal(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're looking for a simpler answer:

```
ROWS = 5

def row( a, b ) :
   return ' ' * (b-a-1) + ' '.join([i for i in str(11**a)])

for i in range(ROWS) :
    print row( i, ROWS )
```

outputs:

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

and if you want this to work in python3, add parentheses in `print( .. )` call.